# how to get the value of x in this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$n= \frac{S}{\sqrt{2\phi a}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-R)^2}{2\phi a^2}\right)$$
I have all the values except $x$, how to get it?
normally without the exponent part it easy to get $x$, I'm pretty confused in getting the $x$ in exponent.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverting the equation algebraically gives
$$
x = R \pm \sqrt{  (-2\phi a^2 ) \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\phi a}}{S}n\right)}
$$
Note the up to two solutions for $x$.

Comment: since there isnt others who answer, i really hope that this is the correct answer, thank you very much for your effort in answering the question.

Comment: You could try to verify it by using $x = f(f^{-1}(x)) = f^{-1}(f(x))$.